# Access Trimble GPS on ArcGIS Engine App

Tags: gps, arcgis-engine, trimble

I have a Trimble Yuma tablet running Windows 7.  I need to build an application that allows viewing of points on a map and editing of a geodatabase (feature layers and tables). I'm hoping to use ArcGIS Engine SDK.

How do I leverage the GPS of the Trimble within my ArcGIS Engine app?  Anybody done this with a Trimble before?  Any code samples out there?

Comment: I googled this in 5 seconds. It may prove useful (or not, honestly) - http://www.trimble.com/yuma-rugged-tablet_ts.asp?Nav=Collection-67287

Comment: @blah238 - thanks, but that is not completely useful.  The API and sample provide methods to get the gps port information, but no info on get actual coordinates from GPS

Comment: I'm guessing you communicate with the GPS unit through the virtual COM port, they just didn't demonstrate how, so perhaps other resources could help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before, but with ArcEngine 9.3.1 and Windows XP / CE.  At the time I think we had issues with the IGpsConnection interface so I rolled my own.

**IGpsConnection Interface**

[IGpsConnection Reference for ArcEngine 10.0](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGpsDisplayProperties_Interface/001200000570000000/)

[IGpsConnection Reference for ArcEngine 9.3](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esricarto/igpsconnection.htm).

**Notes**

You will also need to look at the IGpsFeed and IGpsDisplayProperties interface.

**Usage Example**

To be honest with you I can't dig up any old code, and the API doco is a bit sparse so unless I can find it, you'll have to work your way through it from here.  Will keep you posted if I can get anything.